# Flexbox items spilling over into header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a personal website, and have been using a lot of flexbox to attain the layout I want. I recently ran into an issue that I cannot seem to solve. Where the items in my flexbox container seem to be spilling out and into other containers, such as my header container or past the bottom of where the page should end.

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="projects">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div>
            <h1>project</h1>
            <p>project text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>project</h1>
            <p>project text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>project</h1>
            <p>project text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>project</h1>
            <p>project text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYBbgE

I wanted to use a flexbox layout for my projects section so that the content will be centered, and I like how easy it is to do that with flexbox. If you adjust the height of the codepen container by either increasing the height OR reduce it, you can see that the header is hiding some of the elements.

I have included some HTML to kind of show the layout. I have excluded a lot to conserve space, however the codepen link is much closer to what the actual design looks like.

EDIT: I made a gif demonstrating the behavior that I am having an issue with

[gif of flexbox problem](https://gfycat.com/ExcitableImportantAlbertosaurus)

As you can see, as I adjust the height, the header of my page appears to cover up some of the items beneath it. I also cannot scroll higher than what the height is, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you mean by 'spilling out'? You have a flexbox in your header that is flush up against the bottom, but it doesn't appear to actually be escaping its parent -- it doesn't overlap the other content at all for me in your fiddle. Have you confirmed your fiddle demonstrates the problem? Which element specifically is overlapping with which other element?

Comment: The header should be fine. It's the divs underneath it that are spilling out of their container. The divs in the content-container div. If you adjust the slider of the codepen output box, you can see that the header is covering up elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point out your error, it's the alignment of item's, for all elements you have aligned it center vertically. so it seemed out of a container as it's height was more than viewport. You can fix it by `align-items: center;` to `align-items: flex-start;`

```
.projects {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

and to let you know, i think you are using too flex for everything which can be achieved without it easily

Comment: I tried setting it to flex-start, but that did not seem to fix the issue. I have included a gif in my original post where I demonstrate the issue I am having with the page.

Comment: @wjvukasovic check the updated answer and i think now it will be fine. While answering i think i interchanged `.projects` to `.container`